# como comprobar si la conexion fue exitosa?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, prestashop1.7

hola tengo un modulo que desarrolle para prestashop, y que necesita conectarse con una base de datos externa. Para ello necesito comprobar si la conexion fue exitosa. ¿como puedo comprobar esto? La linea de codigo que hace la conexion es esta:

```
$db = new DbMySQLi("localhost",$user,$password,$database,true);
```

Comment: Con esto simplemente: `if ($db) { //Conexión exitosa, puedes usarla } else { //No hay conexión, actuar en consecuencia }` Esto es posible porque el objeto `$db` será nulo cuando la conexión falle.

Comment: gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

En tu contexto `$db` debería ser `null` o `false` cuando la conexión falle. Entonces, para saber si hay conexión bastaría con hacer esto:

```
$db = new DbMySQLi("localhost",$user,$password,$database,true);
if ($db) 
{
    /*
       Hay conexión, poner en este bloque
       todo lo relativo a la conexión
       ... --- ...
    */
}
else
{
    /*
       No hay conexión, emitir un mensaje de error PERSONALIZADO
       o hacer lo que haya que hacer en ese caso
       OJO: Evita mostrar mensajes de error internos
       en caso de no conexión, por más que el 
       Manual de PHP los muestre en sus ejemplos de código
       A veces esos mensajes revelan información sensible
       de la que los hackers pueden sacar jugosos beneficios
       para explotar tu servidor o tu base de datos
       ... --- ...
    */
}
```